# Labeling point coordinates in path graph using VertexLabels

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, documentation, coding-style, broken-code

**Question:** How do we label point coordinates in `Pathgraph` using `VertexLabels`.

Suppose we have a list of points `S` and rearrange them as pathway `P`.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
S = {{-1.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {1.5, 1}, {1.5, 0.1}, {0, -0.1}, {-1.5, 
    0}, {1, -1.4}, {-1, -1.5}}; (* Random list of points *)
X[1] = S[[2]];  
Y[1] = DeleteCases[S, X[1]]; 
X[x_] := Nearest[Y[x - 1], X[x - 1], 1][[
  1]]; (* Takes X2=x1, X3=x2, X4=x3,... *)
Y[x_] := DeleteCases[Y[x - 1], 
  X[x]]; (* Deletes X1=x0 from the sample S *)
P = Table[X[x], {x, 1, Length[S]}] (* Lists all points in pathway *)
r[i_] := Flatten[
  Position[Nearest[S, P[[i]], Length[S]], 
   P[[i + 1]]]];(* Lists value r_i  where P[[i+1]] is the r_i th
smallest value from P[[i]] *)
ListofAllr = 
 Flatten[Table[
   r[i]/Length[P], {i, 1, 
    Length[S] - 1}]](* List of r[i] for all i *)
DeleteAnomalies[ListofAllr]
IndexofNonOutliers = 
 Flatten[Position[ListofAllr, 
   Alternatives @@ 
    DeleteAnomalies[
     ListofAllr]]](* Index of non-outliers in the list of r *)
D1 = Table[P[[x]], 
  Evaluate[{x, 
    IndexofNonOutliers}]](* Excludes integer i where r_i are outliers *)
DistanceD1 = 
 Table[EuclideanDistance[P[[x]], P[[x + 1]]], 
  Evaluate[{x, 
    IndexofNonOutliers}]] ;(* {x,IndexofNon-Outliers} removes the
distance line segments with index i such that r_i is an outlier *)
arrow[coord_, e_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Style[Arrow[coord], Red, Thickness[.01], 
     Arrowheads[0.06]], 
    Boole[MemberQ[N /@ D1, First@coord]] == 0}, {Style[Arrow[coord], 
     Blue, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[0.06]], 
    Boole[MemberQ[N /@ D1, First@coord]] == 
     1}}];(*Labels arrows for "pathway" P*)
```

Where we attempt to label the point coordinates of the Pathway using:

```
Edge = PathGraph[Range[Length[P]], VertexCoordinates -> P, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> arrow, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotRangePadding -> .2, 
  VertexLabels -> {Table[{i[[1]], i[[2]]} -> {P[[i]][[1]], 
       P[[i]][[2]]}, {i, Length[P]}]}]
(* [Above] Illustrates Pathway*)
```

However, we instead get:

[image]

**Reformulated Question:** How do we fix the code to label the coordinates in the illustration above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VertexLabels -> {Table[{i[[1]], i[[2]]} -> {P[[i]][[1]],  P[[i]][[2]]}, {i, Length[P]}]}` is completely wrong syntax. You can not index a running index "i".

To label the vertices by their coordinates, you must change the numerical  coordinates into strings like:

```
Edge = PathGraph[Range[Length[P]], VertexCoordinates -> P, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> arrow, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotRangePadding -> .2, VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[Length[P]] -> ToString /@ P]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Sorry for the sudden upvote. All the coordinates say $(1.5,1)$. How do we fix this?

Comment: Sorry,  I did not notice this. It is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You could just define PathGraph with P and set VertexLabels -> Automatic.

```
PathGraph[P, VertexCoordinates -> P, EdgeShapeFunction -> arrow, 
 ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> .2, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

Comment: The problem is it's hard for people to visualize where the points are.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the vertex numbers and coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using `Table`:

```
Edge = PathGraph[Range[Length[P]], VertexCoordinates -> P, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> arrow, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotRangePadding -> .2, 
  VertexLabels -> Table[i -> String1[[i]], {i, Length[P]}]]
```

[image]